# How can i remove the useless objects?

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects, so i want to delete the objects without 'first' attribute and if the object is {} and if the 'last' attribute is undefined

> Array(3) {first: '', last: ''} {} {last: undefined}

i tried doing like this:

```
let mapped = []
    mapped = values?.invites?.filter(({ first, last }) => {
     if(first && last)
      return { first, last }
    })
```

but does not worked

note: i need to return an objects { first, last }

Comment: `const filtered = values?.invites?.filter(({first, last}) => first && last)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapped = values?.invites?.filter(({ first, last }) =>(typeof first !=="undefined" && last !=="undefined");
```

Because PO want to keep {firts:'',second""}